# How do I modify every leaf value in a Leaf Labelled Tree by a function

Tags: tree, scheme, racket, leaf

I'm currently trying to modify a LLT(leaf labelled tree) by a function.

Essentially I want the leaf values(L) to be modified by the function(fn)

Here's my code so far

```
(define (llt-map fn T)
  (cond
    [(empty? T) '()]
    [(not (list? (first T)))
     (cons (fn (first T))
       (llt-map fn (rest T)))]                    
    [else (cons
       (llt-map fn (first T))
       (llt-map fn (rest T)))]))
```

The code is actually  working but I have one case I wanted to check and I don't know why it isn't working. I'm sure this is very simple to find out why this case isn't working but I can't figure out why.

Here is the case which isn't working

```
(check-expect (llt-map (lambda (x) (+ 5 (/ x 2)))
                       (list 2 (list 20 30 40) list 8))
              (list 6 (list 15 20 25) list 9))
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my own problem, it was just simple syntax mistake, my bad.

The case should be written as

```
(check-expect (llt-map (lambda (x) (+ 5 (/ x 2)))
                   (list 2 (list 20 30 40 (list 8))))
```

rather than

```
(check-expect (llt-map (lambda (x) (+ 5 (/ x 2)))
                   (list 2 (list 20 30 40) list 8))
          (list 6 (list 15 20 25) list 9))))
```

as I had before.